# Multiple Regex For a single input in laravel with different validation message

Tags: laravel

In laravel validation,

```
'password' => regex:/^(?!.*([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$*%])\1\1)((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,})$/ | regex: /^(?!.*(.)\1\1)(.+)$/
```

How to add custom validation message per regex.

Comment: You should look at custom validation rules: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: i solved this issue by using regex on password and confirm password individually with a condition `same:password `.First regex goes with password and another one goes with confirm password.

Comment: This would be extremely helpful for Laravel to implement as there are many times that fields need to pass a number of regex checks, and each failed check denotes a separate and distinct error. Maybe something like this: `'domain.regex:/^(?!mail\.).+/' => 'This appears to be a mail sub-domain. Please enter just your base domain',` In custom error messages. Where you if you specify the rule and parameter value it will have it's own custom error message.

Comment: then try to extend validator and write your own method to verify regex and you can also pass custom message.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697979/laravel-5-3-use-custom-validation/41698396#41698396

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. if you will use the two regex rules across your application you have to create a rule class using `php artisan make:rule RegexOne` which will create a Rule class defines the rule and the message as shown in the image below

[image]

2. if you will use the rule only in single place you can use a closure like the following:

[image]

Images sources and answeres: https://www.esparkinfo.com/laravel-custom-validation-rules.html