# Laravel 5.3 use custom validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I use Laravel 5.3. I want to use form validation to test the hash for user's password.

Here is my code :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'old_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6',
    'new_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6',
    'new_password_confirm' => 'required|same:new_password',
]);
    
// test old password
if (! Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->user_passwd)) {
    $validator->errors()->add('end', 'The end time must be within three hours of the start');
}
```

This is not working, even if the conditon is verified. I've tested this :

```
Validator::extend('old_password', function($attribute, $value) use ($user) {
    return Hash::check($value, $user->user_passwd);
});
```

But I don't understand how to use this ?

Comment: does it reach " $validator->errors()->add('end', 'The end time must be within three hours of the start');"  ?

Comment: it's show any error

Comment: Yes it reaches. I try with a die('test !'); and die is ok.

Comment: No, it's just that the validator don't fail, even if old_password is not the good one.

Comment: old_password is now a custom validation. so you can use with rules like 'password' => 'old_password'. This will take password a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Your custom rule old_password can be used like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'old_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6|checkpassword',
    'new_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6',
    'new_password_confirm' => 'required|same:new_password',
]);
```

Extend validator. CheckPassword is class with method isValid().

```
Validator::extend('checkpassword', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return (new CheckPassword($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator))->isValid();
        });
```

CheckPassword.php will be like

```
/**
 * Attribute being tested
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
protected $attribute;

/**
 * Value of the attribute
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
protected $value;

/**
 * Array of parameters passed to the value
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $parameters;

/**
 * Validator instance
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
protected $validator;
/**
 * Class constructor
 *
 * @param mixed $attribute
 * @param Uploaded $value
 * @param array $parameters
 * @param mixed $validator
 */
public function __construct($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    $this->attribute = $attribute;
    $this->value = $value;
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

public function isValid()
{
  $value = $this->value; //Old password Value
  //after this you can check hash and return true or false.
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks you give me the way to do this. I wanated to make it in one / two lines, didn't want to create a new file. Solution in my post.

Comment: The purpose of making a seperate file is you can use this code in your several project and in several form request. This prevents repetition of same code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The best way to do it in simple way is to place the extend before the make :

```
Validator::extend('checkPassword', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) use($user) {
     return Hash::check($value, $user->user_passwd);
}, 'Your message error !');

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'old_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6|checkPassword',
     'new_password' => 'required|max:20|min:6',
     'new_password_confirm' => 'required|same:new_password',
]);
```