# Laravel validation rules if field empty another field required

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a Laravel 5.3 app, and an update form where I send user profile values. One of them is user image as well, I am creating a hidden input field for it, so if the user is not uploading any new image, I can still see that he has the hidden field with the old image value.

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="old_image" value="{{ $player->image_filename }}" id="oldImage">
```

If he removes the image, the hidden input value becomes empty.

```
document.getElementById('oldImage').value = '';
```

That is how I thought of updating a user image. But I don't know how to set up validation rules for that form. Something that would be similar to this:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'first_name' => 'required|max:50',
          'last_name' => 'required|max:50',
          'birthday' => 'required',
          'image' => required if old_image empty
        ];
    }
```

I have tried with `'image' => 'required_without:old_image',` and also with `'image' => 'required_if:old_image, null',` but none of them showed any error message for missing image. I am showing error messages like this:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697979/laravel-5-3-use-custom-validation/41698396#41698396

Comment: or you can put if condition in rule

Comment: you can use required_if validation rule .  refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: can you show more code from where you sending hidden variable..?

Comment: @mith I tried this, but I get no error message for it:  'image' => 'required_if:old_image, ""',

Comment: Rule::requiredIf(!isset($request->foo))

Answer (score 48):

You can work with two rules

```
'image' => 'required_if:old_image'
```

Or:

```
'image' => 'required_without:old_image'
```

Comment: Please, remove this extra comma.

Comment: Done! Thanks @MouhammedElshaaer

Comment: doesnt work anymore : Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters

Comment: required_if:old_image,null

Comment: Atm (Laravel 8) `required_if:x,null` isn't the same as `required_without:x`

Answer (score 11):

this is can be done by `required_without` rule, if it's not working please show an actual sample request data ( `dd(request()->all() )`) and the validation rules you are using. the scenario you want to catch is simple: if both fields is empty.

in your example, applying this rule should work:

```
return [
          // ...
          'image' => 'required_without:old_image'
        ];
```

> required_without:foo,bar,...
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any
>   of the other specified fields are not present.
>   [Validation - Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)

Example:

```
$rules = [
        'new_value' => 'required_without:old_value'
        ];

validator(
        ['new_value' =>'',
        'old_value' => 'old value is preserved here']
    , $rules)->errors()->toArray();

// output: [] <-- no errors!

validator(
        ['new_value' =>'New value!',
        'old_value' => '']
    , $rules)->errors()->toArray();

// output: [] <-- no errors!

validator(
        ['new_value' =>'',
        'old_value' => '']
    , $rules)->errors()->toArray();

// output: ["new_value" => ["The new value field is required when old value is not present."]]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Some integrations with Laravel rules require array configuration (such as Folklore GraphQL), and any non-pure validation will not suffice.

Answer (score 11):

For new laravel versions, if you need to use required_if, it requires at least two parameters, so you should use the second and third parameter as if conditions.

```
  'old_image'=>'required_if:image,=,null',
  'image'=>'required_if:old_image,=,null'
```

Comment: 'required_if:old_image,!=,null' don't work..

Comment: Use required_unless:old_image,null

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
'image'=>'required_if:old_image,=,null'
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I came across it during my search. So I'll post my solution here as well for future visitors.

I think this solution is what the OP wants. This solution is not using other packages or custom validation methods so that's a plus as well imo.

What I did was this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'first_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
      'last_name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
      'birthday' => ['required'],
      'old_image' => ['nullable'],
      'image' => [
          Rule::requiredIf(function() {
              return empty($this->request->get('old_image'));
          })
      ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You missing **nullable** validation

```
'old_image' => 'required'
'image' => 'required_without:old_image|nullable'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (empty($request->input('old_image'))){
     $this->validate($request, [
       'image' => 'required',
     ]);
}
else {
     // Validation in case of else goes here
     $this->validate($request, [
      // rule
     ]);
}
```

Comment: this is what i said in comment above,

Comment: There's a Laravel wrapper for this; [`$request->has('old_image')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input)

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
'image' => Rule::when($request->image != null, 'required|string')
```